# Will a persistent supercurrent in a superconducting aluminum ring decay if the ring is connected to a non-superconducting aluminum wire?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity

Will a persistent supercurrent in a superconducting (SC) aluminum ring decay, if we connect the SC aluminum ring to an aluminum wire and the remote end of the wire is located in a separate chamber with T > Tc (or H > Hc)?

This question is more complicated than it seems, most physicists cannot answer it unambiguously and there is no experiments to the issue.
Imagine, a persistent supercurrent flows in a SC aluminum ring. Then we connect the SC aluminum ring (without solder) to an aluminum wire, the second end of the wire is in a separate chamber with T > Tc (or H > Hc) and is not SC. The temperature of the SC ring is stable below Tc. Thus the SC ring is directly connected to a non-SC zone where electron pairs dissipate their supercurrent momenta on atom lattice. Will the remote non-SC zone suppress the persistent supercurrent in the SC ring?

Experimental setup to the question is shown in Figure 1 in

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/373756657_Tuning_of_Lifetime_of_Cooper_pairs_in_a_Massive_Aluminum_Ring

Comment: There is an extensive literature on the superconducting proximity effect, so saying there is no experiments on the issue seems disingenuous,  even if this exact setup has not been studied. Unless the superconducting ring is very thin, i.e. on the order of a correlation length, I would not expect to see any appreciable effect

Comment: The exact setup is very important for the experiment. And opinions about its possible result are very different. It is surprising that this simple experiment is never done.